# Why doesn't C++ initialize variables to 0?

Tags: c++

Why doesn't C++ initialize primary data types to a zero value like some other languages like Java do? Wouldn't this make C++ a better language? Specifically, having pointers start as the null pointer. Is there a functional reason behind this?

Comment: The short answer is that zero initializing isn't free and it would be a shame to force that cost in cases where you don't need it.

Comment: C++ aims at a maximum level of control over performance and efficiency. Such automatic initialization would represent a runtime overhead, in a lot of cases undesirable.

Comment: "Better" is in the eye of the beholder.

Comment: C++ has different design goals than Java. C++ motto is "don't pay for what you don't need". Java (at least thats what I understand) "If it can be used wrong it is out". Not Initializing variables can lead to problems but doing so has a cost.

Comment: *How* would that make C++ a better language? In what scenario is an implicitly zero-initialised value ever desirable? Instead, C++ should simply forbid not explicitly initialising variables altogether. Unfortunately this is currently not possible since some patterns (e.g. `std::cin >> some_var`) rely on variables being present before having a meaningful value. Rust fixes these issues.

Comment: Why doesn't C++ initialize variables to 42?